# Функция удаления узла в бинарном дереве не работает, не знаю, как с помощью указателей присвоить поддерево

Tags: c++, алгоритм, указатели, структуры-данных, бинарное-дерево

Функция должна возвращать указатель на новый корень дерева (упорядоченность не теряется). Меня интересует случай, когда `node->left` и `node->right` не равны `NULL`. Сохраняю правое поддерево во временной переменной-указателе. В старый указатель на корень записываю указатель на правое поддерево (корень правого поддерева становится новым корнем всего дерева). После этого имею правое поддерево в качестве основного и отдельно левое поддерево. Прохожу в правом поддереве до минимального элемента (иду по ветке влево, пока не дойду до конца). И после последнего вставляю хранимое в переменной левое дерево (вставляю в node->left). Все, кроме этого работает, проверял, тестил.

Проблема в том, что у меня  не получается присвоить это левое поддерево. Наверное, это нужно делать через адрес или двойной указатель (гадать не буду...). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы левое поддерево было в node при возврате значения функцией (пока что возвращает правое поддерево. Буду благодарен замечаниям по теории, что посмотреть по указателям, чтобы не путаться и, конечно, ответу на вопрос.

[image: работа функции]

Код:

```
tnode* deleteRootSubTree(tnode* node) {
if (node != NULL) {
    cout << "removing from root" << endl;

    if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    if (node->left != NULL && node->right == NULL) {
        node = node->left;// Присваиваем корню левую часть дерева (от корня)
        return node;
    }
    if (node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL) {
        node = node->right;// Присваиваем корню правую часть дерева (от корня)
        return node;
    }
    if (node->left != NULL && node->right != NULL) {
        tnode* left_node = node->left;// Сохраняем левую часть дерева (от корня)
        node = node->right;// Присваиваем корню правую часть дерева (от корня)
        //нужно левую часть дерева вставить после наименьшего элемента в дереве 
        
        tnode* tmp = node;// Временный узел для прохода по ветке
        while (tmp) {
            tmp = (tmp)->left;
        }
        tmp = left_node;*****// ТУТ ОШИБКА: left_node теряется, тут я неправильно присваиваю левое поддерево*****
        return node;
    }
    
    
    return node;// = *left_node;//<последний наименьший элемент в правом дереве>->left = бывшее левое дерево
    
}
else node;}
```

Структура дерева

```
struct tnode {// Узел дерева
int key;// Ключ
int level;//уровень
struct tnode* left;// Левый потомок
struct tnode* right;// Правый потомок};
```

Comment: А как вы поняли, что функция работает не правильно? Я понял как вы хотите, но не понимаю что вы в итоге получаете. Как понять "_ТУТ ОШИБКА: left_node теряется, тут я неправильно присваиваю левое поддерево_"

Comment: в итоге я получал неправильно сформированное дерево (в нём не было левого поддерева)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл `while` доходит до `NULL`. А вам нужен последний элемент перед `NULL`. К нему и нужно подвесить поддерево. Поправьте код так чтобы он смотрел на один узел вперёд:

```
tnode* tmp = node;// Временный узел для прохода по ветке
while (tmp->left != NULL) {
    tmp = tmp->left;
}
tmp->left = left_node;
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло